# How can I create a session from user input?

Tags: python, post, flask

Disclaimer: Yes I know this might not be the right way to do it, but I just need a quick and easy fix and in this case I prefer the quick and dirty way.

I have a login.html like this:

```
<form method="POST" class="login-form" action="/login">
    <input type="text" name="code">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

I have two types of users who will visit this page. First type of users will have "code_A", second type of users will have "code_B". Depending on which code they will type into the form field they will be redirected to gallery or gallery2.

This is my routes.py:

```
code_A = "code_A"

code_B = "code_B"

@app.route("/login", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    if 'code_A' in session:
        redirect(url_for('gallery'))
    elif 'code_B' in session:
        redirect(url_for('gallery2'))
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        code_post = request.form['code']        
        if code_post == code_A:
            session['code_A'] = code_A
            return redirect(url_for('gallery'))
        elif code_post == code_B:
            session['code_B'] = code_B
            return redirect(url_for('gallery2'))
        else:
            return render_template("login.html")
    else:
        return render_template("login.html")
    return render_template("login.html")

@app.route("/gallery")
def gallery():
    if 'code_A' not in session:
        return redirect(url_for('login'))
    else:
        return render_template('gallery.html')

@app.route("/gallery2")
def gallery2():
    if 'code_B' not in session:
        return redirect(url_for('login'))
    else:
        return render_template('gallery2.html')
```

I though I could simply take the input from the form and create a session based on the input. If the right code is in the session, the user should be redirected to gallery or gallery2, depending on the session. But with this code I always get redirected to login.html and no session is created. How do I pass the input from the form to the routes.py and create a session from it. I mean it cannot be that hard, or is it?

I am thankful for every suggestion, because I am loosing my mind over it. Thanks and best regards!

Comment: Try adding a print statement below this code_post = request.form['code'] and see what code_post is being assigned to.

Comment: well it does kinda work: It creates a cookie and i decoded the session and it holds in fact the code as well as a csrf token. So I don't know where my mistake is.

Comment: in that case it seems to go wrong on the if 'code_A' not in session line. Can you do a print session there to check why that if statement is failing?